# Path.replace(target) does not work with my approach

Tags: python, pathlib

Pathlib is suggested instead of os.module because is newer. However I find less documentation about Pathlib if I look for. I show an issue that give me problems.

**Initial condition**

In a directory I have the following files:
[image]

I want to change the prefix of the files "comune_min_corr_" in "zp".

**OS approach**

With the following code where df4 is dataframe that contain "**comune**":

```
for comune in df4:
    os.replace('./Spedire/comune_min_corr_'+str(comune)+'.gpkg', './Spedire/zp_'+str(comune)+'.gpkg')
```

To be clear, "**comune**" in the following image are three items: Airolo, Alto Malcantone, Aranno. They are part of the filename.

The result is right, the files "zp_**comune**.gpkg" are replaced by the files "comune_min_corr_**comune**.gpkg" and "comune_min_corr_**comune**.gpkg" disappear:

[image]

**Pathlib approach**

I create again the "initial condition".

Then, I try to do the same thing than before, adapting for the "[pathlib.replace(target)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.replace)".
They say here https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/ that we have to use "source.replace(destination)" structure. I did with the following code.

```
for comune in df4:
    Path=('Spedire')
    ('/comune_min_corr_'+str(comune)+'.gpkg').replace('/comune_min_corr_'+str(comune)+'.gpkg','/zp_'+str(comune)+'.gpkg')
```

It give me no error but it does not work, the content of the directory does not change

[image]

**Question**
Could you provide the solution to obtain the same result for pathlib that I obtain with os? Please explain your step and why it does not work for pathlib.

Thank you.

Comment: **nowhere** in the expression do you use pathlib: `('./Spedire/comune_min_corr_'+str(comune)+'.gpkg').replace('./Spedire/comune_min_corr_'+str(comune)+'.gpkg','./Spedire/zp_'+str(comune)+'.gpkg')` where do you think you are using pathlib?

Comment: BTW, [here is the pathlib documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

Comment: @nowhere probably I don't use. To use "replace" is not enough. Show me how to use to reproduce the result of os.replace. os.replace() and Path.replace() should be equivalent. But unfortunately I am not able to use Path.replace().

Comment: you aren't using `pathlib` *anywhere* in your code! you are using the string methods

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I know this link. Before to ask I looked for. But the documentation does not help me.

Comment: you need to create `pathib.Path` objects. You are using `str` objects

Comment: good that you confirm me that I am not using pathlib. Now I need someone that use pathlib to obtain the same result of the os.replace approach.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have added Path=('Spedire') in my code modifying the path, nothing has changed. "Spedire" is my relative directory

Comment: It's looking like you don't actually know what a module is, or how to import one, or how to instantiate a class. You should start by looking that up.

Comment: The module has been imported with "from pathlib import Path". The edited code has now the object pathlib. If it does not have, show me how I have to create. My relative path is ./Spedire/filename.gpkg

Comment: You have to start with `variable = Path('.') / 'Spedire' / (filename + '.gpkg')`. Then you can use `variable.replace(new path)`

Comment: @Barmar I assume that by adding Path(‘.’) to “variable”, you can instantiate with replace. However we also could have: variable=Path (‘Spedire’) / (filename+’.gpkg’).
Right?

Comment: Sure. I was just replicating your `./Spedire`

Comment: the name of the variable: `Path=('Spedire')` is irrelevant. you are still not using pathlib or the `Path` type.

Comment: @Barmar I will change the code later. There is still something strange. Why with os.replace it worked even if I did not have a variable called os containing an object of module os?

Comment: `os` is a module. https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.replace

Answer (score 0):

@Barmar I changed now and it works. Thank you

**To resume:**

with os.replace() it work without defining a variable because replace() is a function of the module "os".

with "path.replace" we have to do so:

```
for comune in df4:
variable = Path('Spedire')/f'comune_min_corr_{comune}.gpkg'
variable.replace(Path('Spedire')/f'zp_{comune}.gpkg')
```

In fact, we have to build an object (here called "variable") because "path.replace" is a class of the module "pathlib". Class always needs to have an object to obtain something because otherwise python does not know what we are talking about.

To be noted: I probably have done something similar, but I repeateadly worked confusing "gpkg" with "gpgk". This trivial mistake leads me in the wrong way.

If I told something wrong, please correct me.

Comment: You can read more about the distinctions between classes, instances, objects, and variables in the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html). Some notes: `Path.replace` is a method of the `Path` class, not a class itself. `Path` is one of several classes defined in the `pathlib` module. Also, the last line of your snippet could be written more expressively as `variable.replace(variable.with_name(f'zp_{comune}.gpkg'))`